# В каком порядке изучать литературу по PHP, mySQL

Tags: php

После изучения html, css, JS(чистого) на начальном уровне, начинаю смотреть в сторону изучения PHP.
Для себя определил следующий порядок:

1. PHP и MySQL. От новичка к профессионалу - Кевин Янк;
2. Разработка веб-приложений с помощью PHP и MySQL - Люк Веллинг, Лора Томсон (под вопросом);
3. PHP 5. Полное руководство -  Джон Коггшолл;
4. PHP: объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования - Мэтт Зандстра;

Хотелось бы узнать подходит ли данная подборка для изучения языка? Возможно какие-то книги дублируют предыдущие и приобретать их нет смысла. Либо чтение такого количества литературы не обязательно и лучше изучать язык на примере какого либо реального проекта, вычитывая материал только по мере необходимости.

Так же хотелось бы узнать какой литературой руководствовались Вы в изучении PHP и что немаловажно, в каком порядке.

Comment: Язык программирования это лишь инструмент для решение, конкретной, поставленой задаче. Так что думаю стоит сделать упор больше на принципы программирования.

Comment: Вы что нибудь одно прочитайте для начала, посмотрите какой нибудь код на php, например несколько cms гляньте. Просто, а понимаете ли вы написанное там. Если не понимаете чего то, постарайтесь разобраться почему так сделано и может узнаете каких еще знаний недостает. По мне так информации в интернете вполне достаточно. Но это по мне.

Comment: А дальше сам книжки пиши:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начинать надо с *Янка*, им же можно и закончить. У него очень внятно изложено именно использование *PHP* вместе с *MySQL* и все примеры и задачи разбираются в комплексе и в привязке к практике. Это значительно понятней и полезней, чем разбирать сначала что-то одно до упора, а потом приниматься за второе.

Читать дальше уже особого смысла не будет, потому что всё остальное будет познаваться из практики и справочных документов.

Answer (score 1):

1. Котеров - дает глубокую базу
2. php the right way(на русском) - дает глубокую новизну