# Посоветуйте правильный путь в изучении php

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Хочу изучить PHP есть большая мотивация и желание. Большее предпочтение в образовательном процессе отдаю книгам. У кого есть хороший опыт разработки на PHP посоветуйте stack книг (видео, web-ресурсов) для изучения (практики) php от уровня новичка к более сложному. Знаю html/css/js писал скрипты, верстал фриланс. В программировании не новичок.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474965/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php-mysql

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а его нет
у каждого он свой
и у всех правильный с его точки зрения
кто то просто доки читает
кто то смотрит скринкасты
ну кому как удобнее
а по поводу книг они устаревают быстро читайте документацию
на форумах общайтесь профильных

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что путь который позволит большее полно и глубоко изучить php поменьше наступая на грабли. В связи с современными тенденциями.